# Apache redirect 443 timeout error

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

My redirection from 80 to 443 port doesn't work.
I have an error timeout
here is my conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Myfolder"

    <Directory "C:/Myfolder">         
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex home.html    
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl/certs/wildcard.mydomain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/private/wildcard.mydomain.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile conf/ssl/certs/wildcard.mydomain.com.pem
    SSLVerifyClient None

    Alias ...

</VirtualHost>
```

But Everything is working ok if I replace

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

with

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

with

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:443>
```

Any idea please ? Thank you.

Comment: do you bind your domain to the port? you can check for it having a look at your listen.conf or httpd.conf 
you can bind the listening of apache to a domain - then, only domain:port would work but not *:port
if there is no real need for binding address and port, simply use _Listen 80_ etc.

Comment: No I didin't bind any domain to the port and I have the Listen 80 option in the httpd.conf

Comment: hmm ok. check _netstat_ in the command line. you should see port 80 and 443 there and the domain(s)/IP(s) they're listening on. if that is ok (i.e. no domain or IP specified), try _NameVirtualHost *:80_ and _NameVirtualHost *:443_ as very first entry in your configuration file (vhosts.conf or httpd.conf).

Comment: Everything is ok now. I've just add "Listen 443" before <VirtualHost *:443> Thank you for your help.